# C - matrix rotation

Tags: c, matrix, rotation

I'm writing a program in C and I need a `M x N` matrix to rotate clockwise. I tried some algorithms, but they only work in `N x N` matrices.

The matrix `{(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)}` should become `{(3,2,1), (6,5,4)}`:

```
1 4
2 5  ->  3 2 1
3 6      6 5 4
```

I wrote this piece of code to transpose the matrix, and now I don't know how to swap the columns:

```html
void transpose(int matrix[MAX][MAX], int m, int n)
{
    int transpose[MAX][MAX], d, c;

    for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
      for( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++)
         transpose[d][c] = matrix[c][d];

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        for(d = 0; d < m; d++)
            matrix[c][d] = transpose[c][d];
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: the obwious thing to do would be to expand the NxM to NxN or MxM whichever is bigger and fill the new lines with pseudo-values, then rotate, and finally remove the pseudo-lines again

Comment: As usual, with any algorithmic problem, the method is the same: 1) How would YOU do it; 2) How would you do it if you were an automated machine only capable of simple step-by-step processing; 3) Implement that algorithm in your chosen language.

Comment: I've just written a piece of code that transpose the matrix given, and now I just need an idea on how to swap the columns.

Comment: Swapping the columns should not be difficult, keep two pointers, one at the first and one at the end, swap the elements, then keep incrementing one pointer and decrementing the other until both overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea. I've implemented it in Java, but it should work in the same manner in C. The idea is to *read the array row major wise from the end, and fill the other array column major wise, from the beginning*.

```
    int a[][]={{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}};
    int m=3,n=2;   //you will need to edit this and actually calculate rows and columns.

    int b[][]=new int[n][m];

    for(int i=m-1; i>=0; i--)
      for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        b[j][m-i-1]=a[i][j];


    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
           System.out.print(b[i][j]+"\t");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output at: https://ideone.com/TveuB5

Comment: Awesome!! Got it, it was simpler than I could imagine!!
Thank you!!