# How do I rotate a matrix? C

Tags: c, arrays

I want a matrix to rotate right. It's working for a square matrix, but i should also work for non square matrix.

I tried rotating it, but i couldn't think of a way to get it to work for non square matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define x 7
#define y 7

int build() {
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    int matrix[x][y];

    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (k = 0; k < y; ++k) {
            matrix[i][k] = i;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (k = 0; k < y; ++k) {
            printf("\t%d", matrix[k][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return matrix[i][k];
}

int turn() 
{
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    int matrix[x][y];

    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (k = 0; k < y; ++k) {
            matrix[i][k] = i;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        for (k = 0; k < y; ++k) {
            printf("\t%d", matrix[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    build();
    printf("\t\n");
    turn();
}
```

i want it to work for diffrent variables like x=5 and y=7.

My thought was to rotate the matrix by 90 degrees.

from

0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1

2 2 2 2

to

2 1 0

2 1 0

2 1 0

2 1 0

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "rotate". Manipulate the matrix so that it has its values in different places? Output the matrix column-by-column instead row-by-row but not change it in any way? Please show desired result or output.

Comment: Just specified what exactly i want. sorry :)

Comment: @AlexUnskilled Are you aware that your program does **not** rotate any matrix? It simply prints two **different** matrix variables that are initialized in different ways.

Comment: @4386427 yes, i am aware of that. I just switched the x and y variables in the 2nd one. I couldn't think of a way to actually rotate it.

Comment: @Lundin alright, then I'll try to figure something out myself. o/

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647682/c-matrix-rotation

Comment: Might I ask, what do you intend to do with the "rotated" matrix?

Comment: Sadly @Lundin there are folk on this site who will do exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little modification to your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define x 3 
#define y 4
int build() {
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    int matrix[x][y];

    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
            for (k = 0; k < y; ++k) {
                    matrix[i][k] = i;
            }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
            for (k = 0; k < y; ++k) {
                    printf("\t%d", matrix[i][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return matrix[i][k];} 
//for right turn you will have to modify the loop like this
int r_turn() 
{

    int i = 0, k = 0;
    int matrix[x][y];
    for(i=0; i<y; i++)     //for outer loop, take y, because you're rotating 
                           //loop , and y will come before x
    {
            for(k=x-1; k>=0; k--)    //thereby, x goes after y 
            {
                    matrix[k][i] = k;
            } 
    }
    for(i=0; i<y; i++)          //printing matrix in the same way we wrote
    {
            for(k=x-1; k>=0; k--)         //here, k will start from k because 
                                          //index starts from 0
            {
                    printf("\t%d", matrix[k][i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    build();
    printf("\t\n");
    r_turn();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

80% of work is declaring your functions and understanding what the declarations mean. You can start like this:

```
#define x 5
#define y 7

void build(int output[y][x]);
```

This declares a function `build`, which receives a matrix, and fills it with the needed data. Note: it doesn't return anything (i.e. returns `void`); instead of returning the data, it receives the pointer which it should write to. This is standard practice in C, because you cannot return arrays from functions.

I didn't write the code for it yet because it would distract you from understanding the flow of information in your program:

```
int main()
{
    int matrix_before_rotation[y][x];
    build(matrix_before_rotation);
}
```

This hypothetical program fills a matrix with values, using your function. It doesn't print it, but you could see the values if you used e.g. a debugger.

To declare a function which does the rotation:

```
void turn(int input[y][x], int output[x][y]);
```

Note the difference in dimensions, and the fact that the function receives two arguments - one for input, and one for output. You need to allocate two matrices in your main program:

```
int main()
{
    int matrix_before_rotation[y][x];
    int matrix_after_rotation[x][y];
    build(matrix_before_rotation);
    turn(matrix_before_rotation, matrix_after_rotation);
}
```

Given this code structure, it's easy to fill in the implementation details.

You might want to add a function for printing a matrix while you are debugging your program:

```
#define x 5
#define y 7

void build(int output[y][x]);
void turn(int input[y][x], int output[x][y]);
void print(int height, int width, int input[height][width]);

int main()
{
    int matrix_before_rotation[y][x];
    int matrix_after_rotation[x][y];
    build(matrix_before_rotation);
    print(y, x, matrix_before_rotation);
    turn(matrix_before_rotation, matrix_after_rotation);
    print(x, y, matrix_after_rotation);
}
```

Note: the printing function is more generic than the generating and the rotating functions - it knows how to work with matrices of any dimensions. You need it because you need at least two types of matrices in your new program - [7][5] and [5][7]. You can use this idea to generalize your rotating function so it could work with matrices of any dimensions.